# Connection and Execution GIT commands using Python

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am trying to connect and execute GIT commands using python such as pull, check status, add and commit new files etc.

I am using python 3.7, PyCharm for IDE and GitPython 2.1.7 as a library. I have also used the following tutorial: https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/first-steps-gitpython.html

But I have an issue with the GIT executable it seems. I have followed the code within the tutorial to the T, barring setting up the environment as PyCharm does this for me.

I am receiving the following error:

*"
raise ImportError(err) 

ImportError: Bad git executable.

The git executable must be specified in one of the following ways:

    - be included in your $PATH

    - be set via $GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE

    - explicitly set via git.refresh()

All git commands will error until this is rectified.

This initial warning can be silenced or aggravated in the future by setting the $GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH environment variable. 

Use one of the following values:

    - quiet|q|silence|s|none|n|0: for no warning or exception

    - warn|w|warning|1: for a printed warning

    - error|e|raise|r|2: for a raised exception

Example:

    export GIT_PYTHON_REFRESH=quiet

"*

I have set my environmental variable "Path" to my Git\bin path as informed by another user on here asking a similar question, but to no avail.

Any help is very much appreciated!

```
import os
from git import Repo


COMMITS_TO_PRINT = 5


def print_commit(commit):
    print('----')
    print(str(commit.hexsha))
    print("\"{}\" by {} ({})".format(commit.summary,
                                     commit.author.name,
                                     commit.author.email))
    print(str(commit.authored_datetime))
    print(str("count: {} and size: {}".format(commit.count(),
                                              commit.size)))


def print_repository(repo):
    print('Repo description: {}'.format(repo.description))
    print('Repo active branch is {}'.format(repo.active_branch))
    for remote in repo.remotes:
        print('Remote named "{}" with URL "{}"'.format(remote, remote.url))
    print('Last commit for repo is {}.'.format(str(repo.head.commit.hexsha)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    repo_path = os.getenv('GIT_REPO_PATH')
    # Repo object used to programmatically interact with Git repositories
    repo = Repo(repo_path)
    # check that the repository loaded correctly
    if not repo.bare:
        print('Repo at {} successfully loaded.'.format(repo_path))
        print_repository(repo)
        # create list of commits then print some of them to stdout
        commits = list(repo.iter_commits('master'))[:COMMITS_TO_PRINT]
        for commit in commits:
            print_commit(commit)
            pass
    else:
        print('Could not load repository at {} :('.format(repo_path))
```

Comment: *I have set my environmental variable "Path"* Please show how have you done it.

Comment: Sure - on Windows 10 i've opened up Environmental Variables setting. Then i've edited the 'System Variables' variable 'Path' .. and i've added a new row to that as: C:\Users\%myuser%\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\Bin.

On git bash i've also ran the following command:
set GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE='C:\Users\%myuser%\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe'

Comment: I think in git bash it shoud be `export GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE=/c/Users/$myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/cmd/git.exe`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion phd - unfortunately i still face the same issue, is there a way to validate that the GIT_PYTHON_GIT_EXECUTABLE is set correctly  ? I am running this on the GIT Bash btw, this is correct ? It does not give me an error, but it does not give me a confirmation message to say that it has successfully set the git executable path

Comment: I ran this on the cmd line and it works fine now - thanks phd !